# Searching an Array using NSPredicate method predicateWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

Currently trying to setup a search would search an Array (bakeryProductArray) which looks like this

"Tea Loaf",
    Tiramusu,
    "Treacle Loaf",
    Trifle,
    "Triple Chocolate Brownie",
    Truffles,
    "Various sponges",
    "Viennese Whirls",
    "Wedding Cakes"

with what the users types into the UISearchbar. I am unclear on how to represent each item in the array in the CFString.

The code I currently have is.

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{

    searchSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd]",searchText];
    //@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@"
    searchResults = [bakeryProductArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchSearch];

    NSLog(@"Filtered Food Product Count --> %d",[searchResults count]);
}
```

Can answer any questions and supply more code if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what your are looking for?

```
NSArray *bakeryProductArray = @[@"Tea Loaf", @"Tiramusu", @"Treacle Loaf", @"Trifle"];
NSString *searchText = @"tr";

NSPredicate *searchSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray *searchResults = [bakeryProductArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchSearch];

NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
// "Treacle Loaf",
// Trifle
```

This finds all strings that *contain* the given search string (case insensitive).
Alternatively, you can use "=" or "BEGINSWITH", depending on your needs.
(More information about predicates in the ["Predicate Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html) .)

Comment: Something on those lines. The array is created from an external data source. The searchText is part of the method call. Will update the code in the question.

Comment: @Evilelement: Now I do not understand the question anymore. What exactly is not working? What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Ignore "Something on those lines" :D Basically want the user to be able to search the bakery array (with the results narrowing down).

Comment: @Evilelement: But your code should do that. Where is the problem?

Comment: It generates an error with *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "self CONTAINS[cd]"'

Comment: @Evilelement: Please have a look at my answer: `@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", ...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36997/discussion-between-evilelement-and-martin-r)

Comment: if main array is NSMutableArray type then it will give different result.